# scrolltop() doesn't work with body.height()

Tags: javascript, css, height, scrolltop, document-body

I've got this Fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/QF47A/3/

Well, I tried a similar code on my website, it worked great until I added a `doctype`. Then the code would always return the `top` from `0px`.

Well take a look: on JsFiddle. It starts from `0`, and the ascends to negative numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add `position:absolute;` to any element in the `DOM` (in english) it gives up it's space just like `float` does. there isn't a way around this unless you add the height to the body.

Basically body doesn't know that #fly is there so body has no height.

If you remove `position:absolute;` you will see

`document.height` will work for you in this case

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33653/discussion-between-dfdf-and-connor)

Comment: i want a way to fetch the whole height of a page

Comment: Thanks, but there's still a problem I want to talk about in chat

Comment: thank you so much for helping me in chat :) Your help was invaluable!

Comment: I've set a bounty to start... in 23 hours I can award it :)